# Can i pass two-dimensional array as property to .asmx webmethod using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, web-services, webforms

i have a webmethod with the signature:

public string SubmitQAResults(int suppId, int result, int[][] qandAs)

I want to use jQuery to call this webmethod. What would it look like? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my advice is use plugin JSON.js ( http://devpro.it/code/149.html )

you can build your 2 dims array:

```
var players = new Array(
["TIME A",20],
["TIME B",25]
);
```

than convert to json and use as param

```
data:JSON.stringify(players);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response! What might the ajax call look like?

$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:2968/MyService.asmx/SubmitQAResults",
            data: "{'players':'" + players + "'}",
            
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data.d);
            }

        });

i am attempting to call an .asmx webservice..

Comment: will look like this

$.ajax({ type: "GET", url: "http://localhost:2968/MyService.asmx/SubmitQAResults", data: JSON.stringify(players), dataType: "json", success: function(data) { alert(data.d); } }); 

i'm not really sure if the JSON.stringify is inside the plugin JSON.js or native...

Comment: ok cool.. so JSON.js is a jQuery plugin or some other "library"?